# Toshiba L755 won't start after BIOS update fail?

Tags: bios, troubleshooting, toshiba-laptop

I bought a bigger battery and read that I had to do an update for it to work. Anyway the BIOS was updating and half way through the power went out and now it will no start. The led's turn on showing that its getting power and you can hear the fan but nothing appears on the screen. I've tried using and HDMI cable to see if its the screen but it shows nothing. What can i do?